# Azure landing zone : Inventory what & how?

Tags: azure, caf, azure-migrate

Currently, I am working on establishing enterprise-scale landing zones for Cloud Adoption Framework in Azure.

I understand that inventory of the existing on premises applications and infrastructure is must to prepare the good landing page architecture.

How do I gather the inventory, is there any tools to do this? What and all should I include in the inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me i think you should use Microsoft Azure Advisor to give you an advice of the cloud infra you would need  and Azure TCO to calculate the difference of the on premises and cloud infra or the Azure calculator to calculate the cloud infra price

Microsoft Azure Advisor: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/advisor/

Azure TCO: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/tco/calculator/

Azure Calculator: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Also i advice you to look for the long time booking 3/5 years; like that you will gain a reduction of nearly 70% of the total price

Hope that my answer helped you and wish that you would vote me up if it did :D thanks alot in advance ....